# Alinhamento pagina css materialize

Tags: javascript, css, materialize, google-app-engine

Estou usando o materialize como framework para uma aplicação. Estou com um pequeno problema na interface dele. Não consigo fazer com que a tabela que exibe os dados da base de dados(uma planilha gdocs), localizada na parte inferior da tela(com bordas) fique alinhada com os demais campos (de cadastro) conforme imagem a seguir. Já alterei de todas as formas o arquivo css e não alinha. Abaixo estão os arquivos do materialize que exibe a página e o arquivo css. E neste link está o projeto, com a planilha spreadsheet e todos os códigos relacionados(GAS e html/materialize). https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GQx3CRWF2KQpQcJaENfEX5HdHG7PhP2waziRy5fXCmo/edit#gid=0

PAGE MATERIALIZE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <?!= include("page-css"); ?>

  </head> 
  <body>

  <div class="container">
  <h1><?= title; ?></h1>

   <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
         <select id="app">          
          <option disabled selected>Auditor Responsável</option>
          <?!= list; ?>
         </select>
        <label>Auditor</label>
      </div>  
      <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input id="prefDate" type="text" class="datepicker">
      <label for="prefDate" class="active">Prazo(se houver)</label>
    </div>

  <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input placeholder="Ex.:Achado 1.1. Falhas nas contratações de TI" id="fn" type="text" class="validate"> 
          <label for="fn">Achado</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input placeholder="Ex.: Discorda-se da conclusão de auditoria pelas razões: " id="ln" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="ln">Manifestação do Auditado</label>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- Close row -->


     </div><!-- Close row -->             

       <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="zip" type="text" class="validate"> 
          <label for="zip">Conclusão de Auditoria</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input disabled id="est" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="est" class="active">Estimativa</label> 
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- Close row -->

      <div class="row">
          <button id="btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small"><i class="material-icons left">access_alarm</i>Enviar</button>

      </div><!-- Close row -->

  <div class="container">

  <div class="row">
 <table class = "bordered striped centered highlight responsive-table"> <h5> DADOS CADASTRADOS </h5>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>ACHADO</th>
              <th>MANIFESTAÇÃO AUDITADO</th>
              <th>CONCLUSÃO AUDITORIA</th>
              <th>ESTIMATIVA</th>
              <th>PRAZO</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody><script><? var data = getData(); ?></script>
        <? for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?= data[i][1] ?></td>
            <td><?= data[i][2] ?></td>
            <td><?= data[i][3] ?></td>
            <td><?= data[i][4] ?></td>
            <td><?= data[i][5] ?></td>
          </tr><?}?>
        </tbody>
      </table>

 </div>
      </div>  <!-- Close row -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

   <?!= include("page-js"); ?>

  </body>

</html>
```

PAGE CSS

```
<style> 
    .table-display th {
    height: 20px;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:center;
  vertical-align: top !important;}

.table-display td {
    height: 20px;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:center;
  vertical-align: top !important;}

 </style>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema é que vc colocou uma `div` com `class container` com o `form` etc, e dentro desse `container`, vc colocou outra `div` com `class container` com a tabela... vc colocou dois `container`, um dentro do outro, por isso deu problema!

Veja que a documentação oficial diz que o `container` tem mais ou menos 70% da largura da tela. Sendo assim quando vc coloca um `container` dentro do outro, o `container` de dentro fica mais ou menos com 70% da largura do `container` pai...

> The container class is set to ~70% of the window width. It helps you center and contain your page content. We use the container to contain our body content.

*Fonte:* https://materializecss.com/grid.html

---

**Apenas removendo a `class container` da `div` que tem a `table` dentro ja resolveu.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Execute em "página toda"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <style>
    table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:4px solid #CCC;
}

#tabela tr {
    border:4px solid #CCC;
}

#tabela td {
    width:4000px;
    height:40px;
    padding:100px;
    border:4px solid #CCC;
}

/*alinha conteúdo da tabela no topo*/
td, th {vertical-align: top !important;}

    </style>

  </head> 
  <body>

  <div class="container">
  <h1>h1</h1>

   <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
         <select id="app">          
          <option disabled selected>Auditor Responsável</option>
          <?!= list; ?>
         </select>
        <label>Auditor</label>
      </div>  
      <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input id="prefDate" type="text" class="datepicker">
      <label for="prefDate" class="active">Prazo(se houver)</label>
    </div>

  <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input placeholder="Ex.:Achado 1.1. Falhas nas contratações de TI" id="fn" type="text" class="validate"> 
          <label for="fn">Achado</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input placeholder="Ex.: Discorda-se da conclusão de auditoria pelas razões: " id="ln" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="ln">Manifestação do Auditado</label>
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- Close row -->


     </div><!-- Close row -->             

       <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="zip" type="text" class="validate"> 
          <label for="zip">Conclusão de Auditoria</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input disabled id="est" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="est" class="active">Estimativa</label> 
        </div>
      </div>  <!-- Close row -->

      <div class="row">
          <button id="btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small"><i class="material-icons left">access_alarm</i>Enviar</button>

      </div><!-- Close row -->



  <div class="row">
 <table class = "bordered striped highlight responsive-table"> <h5> DADOS CADASTRADOS </h5>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>ACHADO</th>
              <th>MANIFESTAÇÃO AUDITADO</th>
              <th>CONCLUSÃO AUDITORIA</th>
              <th>ESTIMATIVA</th>
              <th>PRAZO</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <!-- <script><? var data = getData(); ?></script>
        <? for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) { ?> -->
          <tr>
            <td>lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
        <td>123</td>
          <!-- </tr><?}?> -->
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>


      </div>  <!-- Close row -->

</div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!--  <?!= include("page-js"); ?> -->

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Parece que corrigiu. Só tem um detalhe: o conteúdo da table não tem relação com a largura dela? Ele ainda aparece todo centralizado e no meio de cada célula da table, ao invés de no topo. A coluna "Achado", por exemplo, tem um conteudo, mas como ele está no meio da célula, ele nem aparece na tabela, só seu eu rola-la para baixo. Obs: ele está formatado como no topo no alinhamento vertical da planilha spreadsheet, que é a fonte de dados Vide imagem do conteudo original(editado).

Comment: @rogerroger tira a classe `centered` da tabela, e veja se é isso que vc precisa, dessa forma os textos vão ficar alinhados a esquerda

Comment: Certo, o texto fica à esquerda, mas não alinhado verticalmente no topo da celula, que é o grande problema.

Comment: @rogerroger isso é pq por default o Materialize coloca um `vertical-align: middle;` nas TD e TH, então vc precisa mudar para `vertical-align: top;`. Vc vai ter que colocar no seu CSS algo como `td, th {vertical-align: top !important;}` para garantir o alinhamento no top como vc quer

Comment: Alterei o CSS para aplicar a formatação do materialize, mas não funcionou. Veja o código PAGE CSS acima.

Comment: @rogerroger editei o código da resposta, Execute ele em **página toda** para ver se é o resultado que vc precisa, no CSS deixei comentado onde apliquei o estilo para alinhar no topo o conteúdo.

Comment: Exatamente isso que precisava. Funcionou direitinho, e estou executando em arquivos separados. Muito obrigado.